# MPI_Isend MPI_recv lost data

Tags: c++, mpi

Is it possible that MPI_Recv receive message whose tag does not match?

My logic : MPI_Isend / MPI_Recv communication.

Node 1 Isend a message with tag 0, then Isend another message with tag 1. because there are two threads in Node 1, so the Isend action may happen at the same time.
Node 2 will probe if there is a message coming from Node 1, if yes, then receive the message.

In my design, I want Node 2 to receive the message with tag 0 , then tag 1. But when Node 2 probe the signal that a message is coming from Node 1, it received a message whose length is the same with the tag 1 message. Then no more message from Node 1. It seems that the tag 0 message was lost.

I am so confused, Look forward some answer.

Comment: Your description of the receive process is a bit vague. Do you use `MPI_ANY_SOURCE`/`MPI_ANY_TAG`? Sounds like you combine `MPI_Probe` and `MPI_Recv`. If so, how exactly do you do that? Could you provide concrete code examples?

Answer (score 2):

MPI can not lose messages unless they were sent in "ready" mode, i.e. using `MPI_Rsend` or `MPI_Irsend`, while the receiver was not ready, which is obviously not your case. `MPI_Isend` initiates the sending operation but it is not guaranteed to complete unless it is progressed to completion. Many MPI calls lead to non-blocking operations being progressed but the most explicit ones are `MPI_Wait` and its variants. There are also MPI implementations that have special progression threads that progress non-blocking operations in the background (for exmaple, Open MPI could be compiled this way).

It is possible for the second message to arrive before the first one if it is very small and a different send mode is being used (e.g. some eager send protocol). MPI only guarantees that messages with the same envelope are kept in order. A message envelope is the tuple (sender, receiver, tag, communicator).

Also you speak about sending messages from different threads. Are you sure that your MPI library is thread-safe and have you initialised it with `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` level of thread support, e.g.:

```c
int provided;

MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided);
if (provided != MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE)
{
   printf("Sorry, your MPI library does not provide MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE\n");
   MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thread-safe check suggestion.

Comment: I got this error.How to solve it?

Comment: @user1809434, what MPI implementation are you using?

Comment: $ mpirun -version 
mpirun (Open MPI) 1.6

Comment: @user1809434, the Open MPI library should be compiled with special options in order to provide the `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` level and when such a level is requested and provided, it disables the native InfiniBand support. Check the output of `ompi_info | grep MPI_THREAD`. If it contains `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE: no`, then you won't get this level of thread support, because the library was not compiled with support for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to have the receiver post an `MPI_IRecv` for tag 0 then post an `MPI_IRecv` for tag 1. Then it waits until the messages come in using `MPI_Wait*` which can be `MPI_WaitAll`, `MPI_WaitAny`, or `MPI_Wait` depending on what needs to happen next.

This way you have two receive calls that are sitting and waiting for the messages and the tagged messages go where they are supposed to go.

Comment: It turns out that I should not send data to itself via Isend.